# Evaluate $\sum_{d\mid N}\Lambda(d)$

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions

For a positive integer $n$, define
$$\Lambda(n) = \left\{ \begin{array} {ll}
\log p  & \mbox{if  $n = p^r$,  $p$ a prime and $r \in \mathbb{N},$ }\\   
              0 & \mbox{otherwise.} \end{array} \right.$$
Given a positive integer $N$, evaluate
$\sum_{d\mid N}\Lambda(d)$
where the sum ranges over all divisors $d$ of $N$.

Can I get some help? I have no idea how to solve this problem

Comment: BTW this function is called [Von Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function).

Comment: A proof of this fact is given in Apostol's Analytic Number Theory as [Theorem 2.10](http://books.google.com/books?id=Il64dZELHEIC&pg=PA33).

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 5):

**HINTS**

1. Write $n = p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2} \ldots p_k^{e_k}$. What is $\Lambda (n)$?
2. What are the divisors of $n$?
3. For each divisor $d$, which have that $\Lambda(d) \neq 0$?
4. Did you know that $\log(ab) = \log a + \log b$?
5. Conclude that $\displaystyle \sum_{d \mid N} \Lambda(d) = \log N$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $n =p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2} \ldots p_r^{e_r}$ as $\log(n)=\sum_{i=1}^r e_i \log (p_i)$. Then we have
$$
\sum_{d\mid n} \Lambda (d)  = \sum_{i=1}^r\sum_{m=1}^{e_i} \Lambda(p_i^m) =
\sum_{i=1}^r\sum_{m=1}^{e_i} \log (p_i) = \sum_{i=1}^r e_i \log(p_i)=\log (n).
$$